# sql in ajax display info according to group

Tags: php, ajax

im doing a system will display different content when the user assign to different group.user in group A can view all of the information in group A,but cant view info of group B.

when i doing sql on ajax,there is some problem occur.
do like this will only display customer under one staff only,I want to make it display all the customer served under this group.

```
if($role=="1")
{
    $sqlfriend = "SELECT * FROM `users` where tm_groupid = '$tid' ";
    $friend = mysqli_query($this->conn , $sqlfriend);
    while( $rowf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend) )
    {
        $ans = $rowf["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cusinfo` where AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID = '$ans' ";

    }
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;

}
else
{
    ......
}
$qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot customer data");
    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch customer data");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) 
    { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "current"       => intval($params['current']), 
        "rowCount"      => 10,          
        "total"         => intval($qtot->num_rows),
        "rows"          => $data   // total data array
        );

    return $json_data;
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems. For example you're adding SQL statements in a row and then execute them. This won't work. You have to execute them directly and save the result.

Comment: you can try to modify this row where AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID = '$ans' "; with an IN statament, this will also change your code altogether.

Comment: may I know how to modify?I have been try few way to do it,but still cant get it right